# Count zeros in starting of an integer array until a non zero element in PostgresSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have an integer array column in the Postgres table.
Need to count the number of zeros from starting of the array until a non-zero element is encountered.
If all zeros are present then return -1

For example:

```
int_arr_col           count_zeros_start
------------          ------------------
{0,0,24,34,0,0,34}           2
{0,0,0,0,0}                  -1
{34,34,89,0,0,0}             0
{0,0,0,0,45}                 4
{0,20,80}                    1
{38,80,42}                   0
```

Only while loops seem the option is there any simpler method.

Comment: Can you show your while loop solution, please?

Comment: not implemented that yet, @Bergi
trying a solution where I am replacing non-zero elements with '#', then using array_position(arr, '#') function, so getting 1st position of the non-zero element which is the required count_zeros_start-1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you could use [`UNNEST … WITH ORDINALITY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-TABLEFUNCTIONS) for this, getting the position of the first non-zero element:

```
COALESCE((
  SELECT ord-1
  FROM UNNEST(int_arr_col) WITH ORDINALITY AS els(el, ord)
  WHERE el != 0
  ORDER BY ord
  LIMIT 1
), -1)
```

<sup>([online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_15&fiddle=acb18674bb1b4632e914a67a08916dfc), also including some edge cases around `NULL`s, non-standard lower bounds and multidimensional arrays)</sup>